# Executing code in place of a command in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a command that takes a shell script as an argument.  I'm calling that command from a shell script.  I'd like to keep all the code in one script, so instead of having another shell script as an argument to the command, I'd like to place code in place of the command.  How can I do this with bash?

How the command is normally used:  `command script.sh`

How I'd like to use it:  `command /bin/bash (bash code here)`

Comment: To downvoters: do the right thing and help me understand why it's a bad question.  I'm sure I've seen a solution to a problem like this before.

Comment: Probably because of how unclear your question is. What does that `command` do?

Comment: `command` just runs the shell script in its argument in a special environment.  What I'm looking for will be something like `bash << EOF` with commands after it, followed by EOF.

Comment: if it is a script you've written yourself, please [share the script (or a part of it)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the scenario and test the answers. Else you're encouraging people to guess for answers.

Comment: in `bash << EOF` you are kind of injecting a string in the stdin of the `bash` command and this is called [**heredoc** or here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). It is quite similar to save what you've written between the opening EOF and closing EOF in a file and type `cat <file> | bash`. If you want that you must make your command able to read from its stdin and process what's in it

Answer (score 3):

You could try place code of script.sh within function so you get everything in single file:

```
function replacement_for_script.sh {
code of script.sh
}
```

And then call command:

```
command replacement_for_script.sh
```